# Excel formula with a variable sheet name in range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that has 8 references to a different sheet (it needed ISNA, ISBLANK, and IF statements so it snowballed).

Is there an easy way to change the value in this formulas cell reference without manually changing it every time?

For example:

INDEX(**'2404_Nov'**!$J$2:$J$999999,MATCH(B2,**'2404_Nov'**!$B$2:$B$999999,0))

How would I make it as user friendly as I could to change the `2404_Nov` reference for all occurrences?

Answer (score 1):

Type the sheet name, **2404_Nov**, into cell A1 on the sheet where you're entering your formula. Change your formula to:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(A1&"!$J$2:$J$999999"),MATCH(B2,INDIRECT(A1&"!B$2:$B$999999"),0))
```

The indirect function uses the value in cell A1 as a reference.